# ¿Como alinear input de formulario con labels?

Tags: css

Como podria hacer para que se alinearan los labels de un formulario con sus respectivos inputs? Me gustaria que estuviera el label y el input en la misma línea. Algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento tengo esto:

```
 <div class="form-group">
              <label>Nombre *</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre..." required class="form-control" name="nombre">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <labe>Apellidos *</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos..." required class="form-control" name="apellidos">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email *</label>
              <input type="mail" placeholder="Introduce tu email..." required class="form-control" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Dirección *</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu dirección..." required class="form-control" name="direccion">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer sería utilizar la propiedad `display: inline-block` sobre las `label` para que pudieran coger una anchura y asignarles una anchura fija.

De esta manera, todos los `inputs` empezarían en el mismo sitio.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
label{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Nombre *</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre..." required class="form-control" name="nombre">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Apellidos *</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos..." required class="form-control" name="apellidos">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email *</label>
    <input type="mail" placeholder="Introduce tu email..." required class="form-control" name="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Dirección *</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu dirección..." required class="form-control" name="direccion">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

También podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
form input, form textarea{
display: block;    
}
```

lo que hace este código es que todos los `input` y los `label` te los acomoda y te los baja. A lo que me refiero es que te da un mejor orden osea te pone lo siguiente:

```
Label1  
(Tu textbox)  
Label2  
(Tu textbox)
```

y los textbox estarán alineados

Answer (score 0):

Puedes incluir los label e input dentro de divs y asignarles un width determinado:

```
 <div style="width: 30%">
          <label>Nombre *</label>
 </div>
 <div style="width: 70%">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre..." required 
          class="form-control" name="nombre">
 </div>
```